# Universal Windows App get slected item name

Tags: c#, xaml, universal

i have following xaml code:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Single" Name="MenuBox" SelectionChanged="MenuBox_SelectionChanged">        
<ListBoxItem x:Name="test_item">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Padding="10 0 0 0" FontSize="20" Text="lalal" VerticalAlignment             ="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Now i want to get the selected item Name(!), in this case "test_item" in the selection_changed Event.

I tried:

```
  var item = MenuBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

This string tells me following: "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListBoxItem".
I need the name of the ListBoxItem to change the Scenario accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the name property of the ListBoxItem like this:

```
var item = ((ListBoxItem)MenuBox.SelectedItem).Name;
```